# Are the following compounds aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromaticity

[image: Structures in question]

I know Huckel's rule states that an aromatic species must have $4n+2$ π-electrons. Is the last molecule also aromatic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Molecule **1**, the cyclopentadienyl cation, is not aromatic. It only has 4 π electrons and does not fit the $4n+2$ rule.

Molecule **2**, the cycloheptatrienyl cation (or tropylium cation), is aromatic; it has 6 π electrons and fits the $4n+2$ rule with $n=1$.

Molecule **3**, azulene, is generally considered to be aromatic. It fits the $4n+2$ rule with $n=2$, and is often referred to as a "nonbenzenoid" aromatic compound. It can also be viewed as a fusion of two other aromatic units, the tropylium cation and the cyclopentadienyl anion.

[image]